# Asynchronous test execution issue

Tags: angular, async-await, protractor

I have migrated our Angular JS app to Hybrid app. I am using Angular6/AngularJS (1.6) hybrid app. I am trying to run protractor e2e of the existing e2e tests for angular js pages.
I am running the existing e2e tests using async await. Here I am running two tests in a suite. First few steps of both tests are same. e.g. login->open-page->open-a-pop-up page (in which I am selecting different element in each test case).    While the first test is executing and about to be completed, pop-up screen from 2nd test case appears, before the completion of my first test case. Strange behavior.  Here is snipped which selects elements in pop-up screen in both test cases.

```
this.sendClick = async function(element) {
    try {
      await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', await element.getWebElement());
      return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

My protractor version :

```
protractor": "^5.3.2
"webdriver-manager": "12.0.6",
"selenium-webdriver": "4.0.0-alpha.1",
Node Version: `8.11.3
Angular Version: 6.0.4
AngularJS Version: 1.6.4
Browser(s): Chrome, firefix
Operating System and Version Windows 10
```

Comment: Are the tests in the same file or different files? Does your config set shardTestFiles?

Comment: They are in same file. I haven't set shareTestfiles in config

Comment: Could you provide the tests also ?